# Remove MS Word comments from pasted text

Tags: tinymce

Have been looking all over the web for a solution to this but as yet, cannot find anything.

When users cut and paste from MS Word doc (where it has comments), these comments make their way into the text editor - even though I have the option to remove all of the formatting selected in the Tiny MCE editor.

Is there a way to prevent MS Word comments from coming through a cut-and-paste? Besides obviously telling them to paste it into the HTML code editor.

Comment: Looks like more of a TinyMCE plus browser issue on the front end - I mean on the "pasting from Word" end. Solutions might require provision of typical blocks of unwanted HTML. Wouldn't hurt to have some screenshots, too.

Comment: Will get back to the ticket later with some screenshots. Not very sure about what you mean regarding "provision of typical blocks of unwanted HTML". Could I just create a filter to sit over Tiny MCE so it removes all MS Word comments when they are pasted?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yeah, that's what I have in mind. Some CSS for the Admin setting it to display:none, and a function that removes the blocks on post save. That's assuming (based on past encounters with MS Word, but nothing very recent) that the code blocks are somewhat easily targetable on the same basis. So, when I said "provision of typical blocks," I mean provision by you for our enjoyment. It sounds though like you might already be getting an idea on going about it. I guess the alternative is seeing whether you can customize tinyMCE. I've read about it, never done it.